# Google Storage API - Why is gapi.client.storage undefined?

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-storage, google-api-js-client

I'm new to Google Cloud Storage and I'm trying to create an Angular service to do Google Storage API calls. When I try and list buckets, i get an error:

```
"Error: gapi.client.storage is undefined"
```

How do I ensure that the cloud storage api is loaded and functioning properly?

called from Controller:

```
var apiKey = 'MY API KEY';
var projectId = 'MY PROJECT ID FROM GOOGLE STORAGE';
var clientId = 'MY CLIENT ID FROM GOOGLE STORAGE'

googleCloudService.handleClientLoad(apiKey); 
googleCloudService.initializeApi('v1'); 
googleCloudService.listBuckets(projectId); // <- Throws the Console Errror
```

googleCloudService:

```
/**
 * Set required API keys and check authentication status.
 */
this.handleClientLoad = function(apiKey) {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
};

/**
 * Load the Google Cloud Storage API.
 */
this.initializeApi = function(apiVersion){
  gapi.client.load('storage', apiVersion).then(function success(res) {
      console.log('loaded storage api');
    },
    function error(res) {
      return alert('Error loading storage api: ' + JSON.stringify(res)); // throw error
    });
};

/**
 * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of buckets in
 * your Google Cloud Storage project.
 */
this.listBuckets = function(projectId) {
  var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.list({  // <-- ERROR
    'project': projectId
  });
  console.log(request);
};
```

Comment: It looks like you may be referencing gapi.client.storage before gapi.client.load() invokes its callback.

Comment: so i checked the response from gapi.client.load and it's undefined. it looks like it isn't even loading storage

Comment: It's not returning a promise? How are you loading the gapi library? Something like `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>`? If so, you'll want your initialize call to be inside your `handleClientLoad` callback.

Comment: I was loading it with that same include without the ?onload=handleClientLoad

Comment: Ah, that'll be it. Wrap your 3 initialize calls in a `handleClientLoad` method that you define before that script tag. Example: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html